# How to call Rest Service from PDF opened in a browser using javascript?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to make a Rest call using iText PDFAction(or any other way) when my PDF is opened in a browser. Can somebody help suggesting how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the response to modify the PDF in some way or just execute the call?

Comment: I get a base64 in response which has to be displayed over the PDF.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "displayed over the PDF" and what's the format of the decoded content of the base64?